# Linkage error in Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gcc, compiler-errors, cmake

I have a project which whose structure is defined in the following way (link to project is [here](https://github.com/scap3y/test_cpp)):

```
project_source/
    CMakeLists.txt
    .gitignore
    src/
        main.cpp -> main program file
        windows/  -> contains Unix header implementations for Windows
            CMakeLists.txt
            dirent.h
            getopt.cpp
            getopt.h
        classes/ -> custom class directory
            CMakeLists.txt
            utlities.cpp
            utilities.h
            itk/ -> classes using ITK
                CMakeLists.txt
                basicITK.cpp
                basicITK.h
```

I am trying to use the function `basic::GetImageInfo()` which is declared in **basicITK.h** but the compiler gives a linkage error, saying that "undefined reference to GetImageInfo()" in both GCC and MSVC 2012. I am confused since when I am trying to go to the definition of this function from **main.cpp** using Visual Studio (by pressing F12), it is able to go the definition perfectly fine (which suggests there aren't any issues with the include). In the same vein, when I invoke `basic::fileExists()` from **utilities.h**, it works fine.

I have also tried to have the folder **/classes/itk/** directly as an include using CMakeLists but even that doesn't work. But, when I move **basicITK** class under **/classes/**, it works perfectly fine. However, I would rather keep a segregated folder structure to simplify future extension.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

For ease, I have removed ITK dependency from the project. Now, `basic::GetImageInfo()` has the same functionality as `basic::fileExists()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by making CMake link to **/classes/itk/** from the main CMakeLists. If anyone is interested, I will keep the [github project page](https://github.com/scap3y/test_cpp) public.

Thanks @SNC for the answer but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

ld gives 'undefined reference' when there is a function declaration without implementation. Function 'GetImageInfo' is declared in 'basicITK.h', but the implementation is located in a static library (or DLL - if you use Windows) which you didn't tell ld to include during linking. You must run ld with an option which tells it to link external libraries to your program (for example, on some Linux OSs this option is '-l*defined library name*', so if my program uses zlib for example, then I have to run ld with '-lz' option).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am doing the exact same thing for `basic::fileExists()` as well but it is getting linked just fine (but, when I move **utilities** to another folder under classes/, I get the same complaint from the compiler. Any idea how your answer translates to CMake (since that is what I use to ensure cross-platform support)?

Comment: Perhaps you should look whether file paths are specified correctly in CMake's build instructions. Most problems with preprocessing or linking occur due to incorrect headers/libraries paths specifications (obviously - if linker fails when you move the file to another place). Note that sometimes functions implementations are missing in the libraries while their declarations exist in the headers (this usually happens when new functions appear that do same things in newer program version).

Comment: I am doing the same install for both **Basic_Classes** and **ITK_Classes**: `INSTALL( TARGETS X_Classes DESTINATION lib )` in both their CMakeLists files. I am guessing that if there would have been an error with the file paths, then the functions defined in Basic_Classes.lib wouldn't have been found. Since the install targets are so generic, I am totally confused where the error might be.

Comment: As I mentioned before, functions may simply be missing due to newer code implementation. Make sure you are using the right version of the API and same versions for headers and libraries. Under Windows OS you might need to pass the exact filenames of libraries to the linker, so that it includes them into your project.